# Question about surjective functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ and $T$ be sets and let  $f : S \to T$ be a function. Prove the following:

> If $R$ is a set and $h:R \rightarrow S$ is a function such that $f \circ h$ is surjetive then also $f$ is surjective

Approach: Following the advice of my previous thread, assume for some $r\in S$ and $p \in T$, $f(r)=p$. If we set $r=g(x)$ for some $x \in R$ then $f$ becomes surjective because $f \circ h $ is surjective. How does that look?

Comment: No that's not well written.  You want to start with "Let $t\in T$".  Then work your way back to find $r\in R$ so that $f(h(r))=t$ proving $f$ is surjective.

Comment: why is it wrong? I already saw a right answer , but I don't know why mine fails.

Answer (score 0):

Think of S,R, T as set of cities in three countries of name SS, RR, TT.

Imagine f as a specification of direct flights, with just one flight from each city of SS to cities of TT  etc.

Surjectivity of f means our selection of cities have covered all the cities of TT.

Now given data means $f\circ h$ is surjective. That is flight from RR to TT with one stop in between at SS cover all the cities of TT.  This must be possible only if the second leg covers all cities.

Comment: Yes, I have drawn pictures of it and concluded that f must be surjective, but I don't know how to show it with a mathematical argument

Answer (score 0):

Not quite right. See if you can follow this argument and how it differs from yours:

Assume that $f\circ h$ is onto and that $t\in T$. Then there exists $r\in R$ such that $(f\circ h)(r)=t$. But then $f(h(r))=t$ with $h(r)\in S$. Hence, $f$ is onto. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Mine is similar to yours in the sense that we are concluding that f is surjective because the input is in S. I don't know why mine fails , but I will go with yours because obviously you have more experience than me. Can you explain why mine fails?

Comment: Don't ever go with another answer because that person "seems to have more experience." Try to see the chief differences between my proof and yours. And note Gregory's comment as well.

Comment: but I don't know why mine is wrong.  Comparing my answer to yours is assuming that yours is right

Comment: @TheMathNoob Take a look at your wording for "If we set $r=g(x)$ for some $x \in R$." See if you can tell why that is "not well written" as Gregory says.

Comment: I would believe that we can't set r=g(x) because we don't know  if x maps r under g.

Comment: @TheMathNoob You are *setting* what you are trying to show...